# Setting the media type when using @RequestLine

Tags: java, spring, netflix-feign

I am using @RequestLine annotatin in my Feign Client interface. It only takes the Request Method and Path, is there a way to set the media type it produces and consumes?

This is what I have, any suggestions what ways I can add the media type it produces and consumes to this?

```
@RequestLine("POST /metrics-service/rest/addMetric")
    MyEntity sendEntity(@RequestBody MyEntity toSend);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, very simple, you can add

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
```

check out the reference: https://github.com/Netflix/feign